# Application server monitoring

Tags: tomcat, webserver, weblogic, pega

I support Webserver and weblogic types application servers where Pega application run .
Can anyone suggest any tool that will monitor the Pega application and will sent notice if if it is not accessible.

Comment: If you are looking for an open source product, have a look to the [Prometheus Project](https://prometheus.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Pega has AES (Autonomic Event Services) and PDC (https://pdn.pega.com/products/pega-predictive-diagnostic-cloud) that you could use for monitoring your environments.